# Maven inherit from remote parent

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

My problem is that I have several `git` repos each consisting of several `Maven` projects, and these all need to inherit from a common `pom.xml`.  In other words, they aren't related by file system.  The most obvious solution to me is for the parent to live in a common `Maven repository, however I haven't found any reference on whether this is possible.

I am looking for a solution not involving `git submodule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent needn't exist on the file system. It can be a normal pom-packaged artifact that can be downloaded from a maven repository. So you should be fine.

Comment: How do I tell a pom to download its parent remotely?

Comment: @djechlin just specify `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` in the `parent` element. Don't specify the `relativePath` element.